# Completely splitting the front and backend in web application

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, web-applications

The backend(server) only provide data through api(s), all the page rendering will be done by the front through javascript(ajax).

Generally I think this is a good idea to support multiple clients, for example both the android,iOS,browser can use the same api. Also people may have more clear responsibilities, one can focused on the server or the front only.

However there are some problems I can find at the moment:

1 Reusable layout.

For pages rendered by the backend, we can use some template(layout) libraries like apache tiles to make a uniform look and feel for the while application.

While for the client rendering, none of the ejs,handlebars can fit this.

2 Authentication

Some operations maybe only open for authenticated user, normally we use:

```
<c:if test="${session.user}!=null">
    // put the security operations 
</c:if>
```

While for client rendering, we will have to send ajax to server to make sure the user is authenticated, and then refresh the view, which may cause the rendering steps more complicated.

3 URL parameters parsing

When the pages are rendered by the server, we can get the url parameters easily, for example the `@Param` `@PathVariable`. which means we can create any kinds of urls.

While for client rendering, we will have to build a common libraries to parse the parameters ourselves.

4 ...

I think there maybe more problems I have not mentioned yet.

Then I wonder if this kind of design desirable? If yes, are there any common practices we can follow ?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern frameworks ([ZK](http://zkoss.org/), [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)) go this way. Instead of putting everything into one monolith, all data services are implemented as REST or HTTP services which return JSON. The UI just knows when to make which call and is implemented in JavaScript.

Uniform Look&Feel is not something you aim for; most platforms are slightly different and users expect these differences (Apple behaves different than Android or Windows).

As for authentication, you still need to login to the services (most APIs expect a cookie or they won't work). So that doesn't change.

Comment: When I said uniform Look&Feel I do not mean the same UI for both pc,android or iOS, they should have the common headers,footers title in the PC or android.